# Image should move from top to down

Tags: c#, winforms

I still can not find a solution to my problem.
I want the image to start at the top right corner of the form and go down, then appear at the top in other coordinates, for example (350.0), and go down again.
I wrote the code, but it just goes down and I do not know how to proceed.
I have been offered such a solution, but it only comes down from the top!

```cs
public moving()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    timer = new System.Threading.Timer(Callback, null, 0, 50);
}

private void Callback(object state)
{
    BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(0, pictureBox1.Location.Y + dtY);
    
        // when it touches the bottom of the container
        if (pictureBox1.Location.Y + pictureBox1.Size.Height > pictureBox1.Parent.Height)
        {
            // we already reset once, so no more going back up: stop the timer
            if (resetOnce)
            {
                timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
            }
            // we did not reset yet, so go to middle of container
            else
            {
                resetOnce = true;
                pictureBox1.Location = new Point(370,0);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: maybe resetOnce is set to 'true' initially

Comment: @richej I made it false but it's the same result.

Comment: Note that a  `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` would be much more appropriate for what you are trying to do. Since its event is raised on the UI thread directly, so you do not have to mess about with BeginInvoke.

Comment: Also note that insteade of parent.height you should use its clientSize.Height.

Comment: This code is from my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70366514/2983568) to your previous question, and does exactly what you described in there. Now you're changing the requirement. I suggest you try to understand what the code does, it is quite simple to modify it to do what you really want.

Comment: I think you're makiing this more complex than it needs to be. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353301/move-the-label-from-left-to-right-and-right-to-left/70353861#70353861 with the addition that you stop the timer at some point

Comment: @CaiusJard I don't know what the problem is but it only goes in one direction and doesn't appear in my desired coordinates.

Comment: But where do you repeatedly *change anything* that would make it move? For example, where do you change `dtY` ? See the code I posted to the other person about  moving a label. I repeatedly add some pixels to its Left; you could repeatedly add some pixels to its Top if you want to move it downwards. I also reverse the direction of the label by inverting step variable from 10 to -10 at some point, so instead of adding to Left it takes away (moving it twoards the left of the window)., You could just Stop the timer at that point, and the picture stops moving